# Why is my division operation returning 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my first question on this website, thanks for helping. I have a web application I'm trying to make, but it always returns 0 whenever I do a division operation. The end goal is to get the correct output and display it to my label on my webpage, and whenever I do a simple operation for testing, like 1+2, it is correct. Here's some code, this first block refers to the webpage logic itself.

```
    public partial class Length : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {
                Conversion convertObj = new Conversion();
                double userIntLength = double.Parse(txtLengthInput.Text);
                double convertedLength = convertObj.Length;
                lblResult.Text = convertedLength.ToString();
            }
        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ddlLength.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                lblUnits.Text = "Miles";
            }
            if (ddlLength.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                lblUnits.Text = "Kilometers";
            }
            if (ddlLength.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                lblUnits.Text = "Feet";
            }
            if (ddlLength.SelectedIndex == 4)
            {
                lblUnits.Text = "Yard";
            }
            if (ddlLength.SelectedIndex == 5)
            {
                lblUnits.Text = "Centimeters";
            }
            if (ddlLength.SelectedIndex == 6)
            {
                lblUnits.Text = "Inches";
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the business layer logic, and also where I think the issue is.

```
 public class Conversion
    {
        double length;
        public double Length
        {
            get
            {
                double total = (((double) length) / 1.609344);
                return total;
            }
            set
            {
                length = value;
            }
        }


    }
```

Doing some google-fu, everyone says it's because of the data types, but everything is casted into double so I'm not sure why that is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never actually setting the length value in the Conversion class, if defaults to 0, so the answer will always be 0

Answer (score 1):

You never assign a value to `Conversion.Length` property, so the `Conversion.length` field value is `0` and `0 / 1.609344` is still `0`.

You may change your code to

```
Conversion convertObj = new Conversion();
convertObj.Length = double.Parse(txtLengthInput.Text);
double convertedLength = convertObj.Length;
```

BTW

In the `Length` getter you cast the `length` field to `double` although it is already decalred as `double`. So this is useless, and you can simply write

```
public class Conversion
{
    double length;
    public double Length
    {
        get
        {
            double total = length / 1.609344;
            return total;
        }
        set
        {
            length = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver, that did it! Now I can finally continue.